# How to replace a complete property file with another while maven build

Tags: maven

I am having email.properties(development) in my application under resources folder. This file has to be overwrite another file (email.properties for production) during maven build. Could you please suggest steps to achieve this. I have gone through some process to change values with in property file by using tokens. But that is not my actual requirement, if I keep tokens like mail.id={your.mail} i am unable to use it in my local host because i am not doing any maven build and deploying war file in my JBOSS for localhost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the maven resources plugin to overwrite the resource with another one

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-properties</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources/prod</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>environment.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

You can bind it to a profile in case you don't always need an overwrite.

Comment: I have wirtten it by adding profiles. <profile> <id>prod</id> <build> <plugins> ... </profile>. I am trying to build it from eclipse by clicking run as->run configurations and giving profile as prod. But I am getting errors, unable to build. Please help me on this.

Comment: please add your pom configuration and the errors to the question as an update.

Comment: ok here I am attaching my pom.xml. Sorry I am not finding attach file button file here. If I am pasting complete pom.xml it exceeding characters size.

Comment: @SarveshV  - I can't, only you can mark it answered http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow :)